Ошибка при обновлении Source в Image
Написал вот такой код для того чтоб отобразить в WPF окне картинку, переданную клиентом:
namespace ScreenStream
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private TcpListener _listener;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            StartServer();
        }

        private async void StartServer()
        {
            _listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 12345);
            _listener.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                var client = await _listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
                _ = Task.Run(() => HandleClient(client));
            }
        }

        private async Task HandleClient(TcpClient client)
        {
            using (var networkStream = client.GetStream())
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await networkStream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                memoryStream.Position = 0;

                var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                bitmapImage.BeginInit();
                bitmapImage.StreamSource = memoryStream;
                bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                bitmapImage.EndInit();

                Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    ScreenshotImage.Source = bitmapImage;
                });
            }
            client.Close();
        }

        protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
        {
            _listener?.Stop();
            base.OnClosed(e);
        }
    }
}

проблема в том, что ScreenshotImage.Source = bitmapImage; выдает ошибку System.InvalidOperationException: 'The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.'.
Пробовал чисто в качестве бреда по разному обьявлять Dispatcher, например:
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    ScreenshotImage.Source = bitmapImage;
});

или
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    ScreenshotImage.Source = bitmapImage;
});

но результат всяко тот же, что впринципе не удивительно, а других идей как решить пробелму у меня нет погуглил, везде пишут что ошибка фикситься простым добавлением Dispatcher.Invoke, а мне это почему то не помогло

Dispatcher.Invoke указывает на то, что код в его блоке должен выполняться в основном потоке. Без него вы бы не смогли взаимодействовать с UI-элементами в асинхронной задаче. А исключение System.InvalidOperationException: 'The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.' как раз говорило об этом :)

Я понимаю, когда код называют "плохим" - это можно расценивать как оскорблением и сразу надо кидать жалобы, удалять... Но не забывайте о том, что все мы учимся, а учиться надо изначально правильному, ибо можно потратить уйму времени на то, от чего потом будет очень трудно отучиться. Также не забывайте, что контент на SO пишется для будущих читателей, которые захотят знать, что не стоит так делать. Боже, если бы мне это сказали в самом начале, я на всю жизнь был бы обязан тому человек, но увы... Так что, задумайтесь. Повторю - привязки, научитесь, таких проблем может быть даже и вовсе не будет.

Я жалобы не кидал, и коментарий не удалял

@EvgeniyZ подтверждаю, комментарий удалил я по тревоге не от автора вопроса. Стоило его сформулировать более предметно. Оценка - это неплохо, но без минимального конструктива такая оценка может быть воспринята не так как вы бы ожидали. Как говорят "критикуешь? - предлагай". С другой стороны этот код не плохой, он просто просто эксперименталиный. Никто серьёзно не будет запихивать TcpListener в десктопное приложение для продакшн решения, я имею в виду этот код нежизнеспособен изначально, и не только потому что в нём не используются биндинги. Думаю, можно было бы отнестись снисходительнее.

Автору примеры: раз, два, три. И сервер надо выносить из десктопного приложения. Десктопное приложение должно стать клиентом.

@aepot Когда я пишу комментарии, я пишу что стоит поправить, в удаленном это тоже было указано, так что - предложил, удалили... Ну а дальше уже все зависит от автора вопроса и от других людей, захотят разобраться как правильно - с радостью помогу и даже может дам ответ (если это потребуется) с переписанным кодом. Ну а если человеку это не надо, его устраивает текущий вариант, то что, мне тратить часы своей жизни на пустоту? Извините, я пасс... И да, даже "экспериментальный" код должен быть написан правильно, теж привязки - это другое мышление, которое на автомате используется везде.

Проблема связана с тем, что BitmapImage должен быть инициализирован на основном потоке, прежде чем его можно будет использовать в Dispatcher.Invoke.
Попробуйте создать и инициализировать BitmapImage внутри Dispatcher.Invoke таким образом:
Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    bitmapImage.BeginInit();
    bitmapImage.StreamSource = memoryStream;
    bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bitmapImage.EndInit();

    ScreenshotImage.Source = bitmapImage;
});

